# Show that every finite simple group G has a faithful irreducible representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

A representation $ \rho $ : G  $ \rightarrow $ GL(V) is faithful if ker($ \rho $)={$ e $}.

A representation is irreducible if it contains no proper invariant subspaces

G is a simple group its normal subgroups are {$ e $} and itself.

Is there anything that can link these together to prove the above statement?

Comment: I would try $V=\mathbb{R}[G]$ and $\rho(g)(x)=gx$.

Comment: The kernel of $\rho$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Conversely, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then it is the kernel of some irreducible representation, or the intersection of two or more such kernels. If $G$ is simple, then the irreducible representations have trivial kernels, so they are faithful.

Comment: Just to cause a bit of unnecessary confusion, note that a cyclic group of order $p$ has no faithful irreducible representation in characteristic $p$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson — your comment makes more sense to me than the answer below. Would your proof also work if one needed to show for an arbitrary finite simple group G that there exists an integer n ⩽ the square root of |G| s.t. G has a faithful representation with degree n?

Comment: @mathmajor, the squares of the degrees of the irreducible representations add up to the order of the group, so all the irreducible representations have degree less than the square root of the order of $G$ (provided $G$ isn't the one-element group).

Answer (score 1):

Exercise: let $G$ be a simple group and fix a field $K$. Then every nontrivial linear representation of minimal dimension is faithful and irreducible unless $G$ is cyclic of order $p$ and $p=0$ in $K$. In particular, if the simple group $G$ admits a nontrivial linear representation over $K$ (e.g., $G$ is finite), then it admits a faithful irreducible representation (with the same unique exception in char. $p$)