# Has every infinite simple group a faithful irreducible representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, simple-groups, infinite-groups

> Has every infinite simple group a faithful irreducible representation?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246536/show-that-every-finite-simple-group-g-has-a-faithful-irreducible-representation) solves the finite case. However, the proof requires a non-trivial linear representation of a finite group. I want to know if the conclusion is true for an infinite simple group. If it is not, can you give me a counterexample?

Comment: You should specify if the representation is finite-dimensional or not.

Comment: I have only learned finite dimension representation of groups, and the question was under the finite dimension representation condition when I asked. But it is nice to see a more general result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is true for infinite groups with some exceptions if you allow infinite-dimensional representations

Unless $G$ is a p-group, where $p$ is the characteristic of $k$, the group ring $k[G]$ is not local, so there exist at least two isomorphism classes of simple modules, in particular, there is an irreducible representation where $G$ acts nontrivially.

Such a representation is faithful, because $G$ is simple and so any nontrivial homomorphism from $G$ is injective.

Conversely, if $G$ is $p$-group (such as a Tarski monster), where $p$ is the characteristic of $k$, then $k[G]$ is local and hence there is only one irreducible representation, the trivial one, which is not faithful.

Answer (score 2):

When a ring has a faithful simple right module it is called **right primitive**.  A faithful simple $R[G]$ module yields a faithful irreducible representation, so looking at when $R[G]$ is right primitive might be fruitful.

At one time, right primitive group rings (other than obvious ones like the semisimple ones) were scarce.  You might be interested in seeing the following paper that observed how to get a class of more interesting examples:

> Formanek, Edward, and Robert L. Snider. ["Primitive group rings."](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-036-02/S0002-9939-1972-0308178-8/S0002-9939-1972-0308178-8.pdf) Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society 36.2 (1972): 357-360.

A better known theorem is that $R[G]$ is prime if $R$ is prime and $G$ has no nontrivial finite normal subgroups.  Right primitive rings are prime, so it is a necessary condition for $R[G]$ to be right primitive. Requiring $G$ to be simple is sufficient to say $R[G]$ is prime, but it's not enough to get primitivity.

Comment: Note: a faithful representation of $G$ is not necessarily a faithful $R[G]$-module.

Comment: @LukasHeger Huh... I'm not sure at what point that misconception boarded my brain.  Reexamining, it looks like even if a map out of $G$ is injective, the corresponding map out of $R[G]$ may not be injective?  It looks like a faithful $R[G]$ module gives you a faithful $G$ representation though... there's no problem in that direction right?

Comment: @LukasHeger (Note: I'm trying to edit around this mistake of mine and hopefully salvage something valuable.)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, faithful as a module implies faithful as a representation, but not conversely

Comment: @LukasHeger Wow, thanks for catching me on this. The correspondence is nice in so many other ways, but I guess I thought it was too nice.

Comment: I think primitivity of group rings is a more delicate question than the question about faithful irreps, see my answer.

Comment: @LukasHeger yes, it is indeed far more delicate.

Answer (score 1):

In [GROUPS WITH NO NONTRIVIAL LINEAR REPRESENTATIONS](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/57880A0DEA486093A4761AFD5D87E02A/S0004972700009503a.pdf/groups-with-no-nontrivial-linear-representations.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20extreme%20subclass%20of%20counter-linear%20groups%20is%20the,or%20equivalently%2C%20if%20G%20involves%20all%20finite%20groups.) by A.J. BERRICK. Example 1.3 gives a simple, locally finite group which has only trivial linear representation.
Thus it has no faithful irreducible linear representation.

I searched on Google for some relevant results and found it eventually by hours, may it be helpful to the late-comers.

Comment: When you cite a paper it would be helpful (and standard practice) to mention the author, as well as providing a web link.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have added the author now. Thank you

Comment: This paper appears to be only talking about *finite-dimensional* representations.  Every group has a faithful linear representation (the regular representation), though it may not be finite-dimensional.

Comment: I have only learned finite dimension representation of groups, and the question was under the finite dimension representation condition when I asked. But it is a pleasure to see a more general result.